# Use variable to get value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following `getJSON` which was working fine. I decided I wanted to be able to change the data shown on the page based on what the user selected. I have a function that sets a cookie based on the user selection. I want to take the value of this cookie and use it to get a specific value from the JSON object.

The value of the cookie is retrieved and stored in `cohort1`.

```
$.getJSON('all_get_login.php?cat_code=stocks&sortvalue=value&sortorder=asc', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if (val.value == "Yes") {
            var cohort1 = readCookie('cohort_id_1');
            console.log(cohort1); //gives expected result
            var databaseYes = val.cohort1; //THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
            var databaseNo = 100 - databaseYes;
            $("#yes_stocks_db").append(databaseYes + "%");
            $("#no_stocks_db").append(databaseNo + "%");
    });
});
```

My JSON object looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "cat_code": "stocks",
        "group": "fin",
        "main_grouping": "Financial",
        "highest_level": "Financial",
        "category": "Invests in Stocks and Bonds",
        "value": "No",
        "database_percent": "38.90",
        "cohort_1": "43.88",
        "cohort_2": "27.66",
        "national_percent": "30.16"
    },
    {
        "cat_code": "stocks",
        "group": "fin",
        "main_grouping": "Financial",
        "highest_level": "Financial",
        "category": "Invests in Stocks and Bonds",
        "value": "Yes",
        "database_percent": "61.10",
        "cohort_1": "56.37",
        "cohort_2": "72.34",
        "national_percent": "70.10"
    }
]
```

Here's the problem: in the line in my `getJSON`that has this `var databaseYes= val.cohort1;`, the script is looking for something in the JSON object that matches "cohort1", which will never be in the object. What I need in here is the value of the var `cohort1` and not the actual text "cohort1". How can I change this line to accommodate that?

Comment: Is your if-block missing a closing-brace?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is a `$.each` loop there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I change that one line to (for example): `var databaseYes = val.database_percent;` where "database_percent" is something in the JSON object, it works just fine. The problem is when I try to pass a variable in there instead of something from the actual JSON.

Comment: I think you might mean  `var databaseYes = val[cohort1]` ? Objective is not easy to understand as written. Perhaps an example value of the cookie would help

Comment: @charlietfl That was exactly it. Thanks. Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @YerkoPalma thank you - I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` object notation to pass a variable as a property name.

```
var cohort1 ='foo';
var databaseYes = val[cohort1];
```

This is the equivalent of `val.foo`